# How To Access Value From Foreach Loop For Hidden Input?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Here I am trying to get the value form hidden type input`<input type="hidden" id="msg" value="1" />` which is inside the foreach loop and inside the table row using jquery. But my script returns nothing.
SO any assistance with my approach will be a great help.

Below is my html

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <input type="hidden" id="msg" value="1" />
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.studentid, new { @id = "studentidforRejectectionadmission" })
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fullname)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.classname)</td>
</tr>
}
```

Below is my script for  accessing value

```
$("tr").find('input#msg').val();
```

Comment: Your hidden inputs got same id... "msg"

Comment: Side note: invalid HTML (with duplicate IDs) can produce undefined results just fine... Please decide if you have HTML/jQuery question (and show HTML instead of CSHTML) or C#/CSHTML (than you need to show some C# code too)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments you have same id "msg". 
Instead of using multiple id's I would suggest you to use a class "msg" for input instead.

If it's important that you match like u did with table row then input with id msg:

```
$("tr").find('input#msg').val();
```

The equivalent would be

```
$("tr > input.msg").val();
```

If you want to access a specific hidden input you can access like:

```
$("tr > input.msg")[1].value;
```

To show you how it works I created a dotnetfiddle for you. Maybe the problem you facing is that you missed to create a table tag surrounding your code to work properly otherwise you cannot have a table row...
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jt7KGp

Comment: @Adhi which part is not working for you? If you describe in more words I can help you

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **id** and put **class**, cause id is unique in the html  and
class can repeat the class name in any elements

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" class="msg" value="1" />
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.studentid, new { @id = "studentidforRejectectionadmission" })
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fullname)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.classname)</td>
    </tr>
    }
```

> now you can access the input value by the jquery eloquent selector

```
let val = $("tr").find('.msg').eq(0).val();
console.log(val);
```